# MailChimp export api with static segment

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use export api to get information of a saved segment of a list on MailChimp. I can get result from MailChimp if I change the segment field to "email" and segment op to "like"; when I use the segment field "static_segment", it says

> "error": "Something went wrong, please try again later."
>   "code": 506

My request url is like following -

https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list?apikey=$apikey&id=$list_id&segment[match]=all&segment[conditions][0][op]=eq&segment[conditions][0][field]=static_segment&segment[conditions][0][value]=$segment_id

Could anyone share his/her solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: The query parameters that you used work for me.